# In python+aiohttp, are the routes multithreaded? How can I communicate between the routes while their code is running?

Tags: python, multithreading, aiohttp

I have a python-aiohttp web service.  I want to have the routes interact with each other in this way:

```
# http://base/pause
async def pause_server(self, request):
    self._is_paused = True
    return json_response(data={'paused': true})

# http://base/resume
async def resume_server(self, request):
    self._is_paused = False
    return json_response(data={'paused': false})

# http://base/getData
async def get_data(self, request):
    while self._is_paused:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return json_response(data=data)
```

I've found that if I call `pause_server`, and then in a separate tab call `get_data`, the server sleeps as I expect, but once I call `resume_server`, the `resume_server` code never gets called and the server continues to sleep indefinitely in the `get_data` code.  Is this something I can do with python-aiohttp?  I would've guessed that each route runs on its own thread, but if that were the case, I'd have expected this code to work.

Why do I want to do this?  I'm doing some behave testing of a python application which uses aiohttp to host REST services.  While my page is loading, I want to show some "Loading..." text on the screen.  When I write my behave tests now, they look like this:

```
Scenario: Load the page
    Given the server takes 5 seconds to respone
    And I go to the page
    Then the data is 'Loading...'
    Given I wait 5 seconds
    Then the data is '<data>'
```

This relies on the server taking a certain amount of time to run.  If I set the server to wait too long, the tests take forever to run.  If I set the wait too short, the tests start to fail because it takes a while to actually run them.

I'd rather do something like this:

```
Scenario: Load the page
    Given I pause the server  # calls pause_server endpoint
    And I go to the page  # calls get_data endpoint
    Then the data is 'Loading...'
    Given I resume the server  # calls resume_server endpoint
    Then the data is '<data>'
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but you should use `await asyncio.sleep` instead of calling `time.sleep`

Comment: @yorodm, that was the answer `await asyncio.sleep`  Thanks! You can read the second part of my question to see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Read about [asyncio-sync](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio-sync)